# strange Cannot be referenced from a static context error in Java

Tags: java

Wondering - why there is such error message during compile:

> ClassHierarchyTest1.this Cannot be referenced from a static context

Source code:

```
public class ClassHierarchyTest1 {
    class Foo {
        int a;
        Foo(int b) {
            this.a = b;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Foo f = new Foo(1); // this line has the error message
    }
}
```

Comment: Inner classes are treated in the same way as members. Yours seems to be bound to instances of it's enclosing class

Comment: Please note: you are still allowed to accept one of the answers ... so please dont forget about that ;-)

Answer (score 2):

`Foo` is an inner class and therefore you can access it only through instance of `ClassHierarchyTest1`. Like that:

```
 Foo f = new ClassHierarchyTest1().new Foo(1);
```

Another option is to define `foo` as static:

```
static class Foo{...}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not at all strange.

Your inner class itself is not static. Thus it always needs an object of the outer enclosing class. Which you don't have in your static main.

So you have to change Foo to be static (of course you then can't use the "outer this"), or you have to create an instance of your outer class first,and call new on that object.

Answer (score 1):

Foo is a member of    `ClassHierarchyTest1` . Hence you have to use `ClassHierarchyTest1` inorder to access it's members.

Docs of [Inner Classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html)

> An instance of InnerClass can exist only within an instance of OuterClass and has direct access to the methods and fields of its enclosing instance.

```
class OuterClass {
    ...
    class InnerClass {
        ...
    }
}
```

To instantiate an inner class, you must first instantiate the outer class. Then, create the inner object within the outer object with this syntax:

```
OuterClass.InnerClass innerObject = outerObject.new InnerClass();
```

Answer (score 0):

add static to your class

```
public class ClassHierarchyTest1 {

class static Foo {
    int a;
    Foo(int b) {
        this.a = b;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Foo f = new Foo(1); // this line has the error message
}
}
```

Comment: This isn't much of an answer. A suggestion without explanation isn't very helpful.