# Non-static Cannot Be Referenced From static,when using args

Tags: java, static-methods

Here are the code.
Error happens at 2rd line.

```
public class TestStack1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FixCapacityStackOfString fcstack = new FixCapacityStackOfString(100);
        for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
            fcstack.add(args[i]);
        }
    }


    class FixCapacityStackOfString {

        public FixCapacityStackOfString(int a) {
            list = new String[a];
        }

        private int size;
        private String[] list;


        public int size() {
            return size;
        }

        public boolean isEmpty() {
            if (size == 0) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }

        public String push() {
            return list[--size];
        }

        public void add(String s) {
            list[size++] = s;
        }
    }
}
```

Because it uses the args,I can't move the main method into a method in public class.How can I correct it?

Comment: What error? Third line of what? What uses `args`?

Comment: please provide more code along with error

Comment: The `main` method is an entry point into your application when it’s started and not some method you can call or otherwise include in your own classes if that is what you are trying to do.

Comment: You should study about objects, classes and methods. You have not posted your full code, but I suspect `FixCapacityStackOfString` is a nested class. Since this nested class is not `static`, you need an instance of the enclosing class.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [strange Cannot be referenced from a static context error in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43164735/strange-cannot-be-referenced-from-a-static-context-error-in-java)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Non-static variable cannot be referenced from a static context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2559527/non-static-variable-cannot-be-referenced-from-a-static-context)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a great question which shows the magic of "static" keyword.

Your program can be executed in three ways:

> First Way: When the class FixCapacityStackOfString  is a nested class.

```
class ClassName
{
public static void main(String[] args) {

    ClassName obj = new ClassName();
    FixCapacityStackOfString fcstack =   obj.new FixCapacityStackOfString(100);
}

class FixCapacityStackOfString {

    public FixCapacityStackOfString(int a) {
        list = new String[a];
    }

    private int size;
    private String[] list;
    }

}
```

In this, the invocation of a constructor which is, non-static method, requires an instance of the class in which it is defined. Since you're calling from static method main, this is how you have to invoke.

> Second Way: If you class FixCapacityStackOfString is outside the main class

```
class ClassName
    {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        FixCapacityStackOfString fcstack =   new FixCapacityStackOfString(100);
    }


    }

class FixCapacityStackOfString {

        public FixCapacityStackOfString(int a) {
            list = new String[a];
        }

        private int size;
        private String[] list;
        }
```

> Third Way: Declare the class FixCapacityStackOfString  as static inside first class.

```
class ClassName
{
public static void main(String[] args) {

    FixCapacityStackOfString fcstack = new FixCapacityStackOfString(100);
}

static class FixCapacityStackOfString {

    public FixCapacityStackOfString(int a) {
        list = new String[a];
    }

    private int size;
    private String[] list;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks like this:

```
class TestStack1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) { ... }
    class FixCapacityStackOfString { ... }
}
```

And you use `FixCapacityStackOfString` in `main`. But `FixCapacityStackOfString` is not a static class: it requires an instance of `TestStack1`. You don't have this instance in static main method. So just declare `FixCapacityStackOfString` as static:

```
static class FixCapacityStackOfString { ... }
```